# How to open a file explorer with a python script on Blender

Tags: python, blender

I would like to open a file explorer limited to `.png` and `.jpg` image file types, with a predefined path and I would like the code to stop the script as long as the function returns nothing. Once the image is selected the code continues.

```
bpy.ops.image.open('INVOKE_DEFAULT', filter_image=True, filter_movie=False)
```

I want to stop the code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your app? What libraries are you using for your GUI (Graphical User Interface)